# DialogBox crash in Win7

Tags: c++, mfc

I have windows application developed in VC++. I am using a CFileDialog to display a dialog box . However the moment I right click on the dialog box , it crashes . The same code works fine in XP . I read some where that the Vista Style is no longer supported . So I modified the code as follows. Still I get a crash

```
CFileDialog dlg(FALSE, _T("*.xml"),strFileName ,OFN_HIDEREADONLY, 
                         _T("(*.xml)|*.xml|(*.*)|*.*||"), NULL, 0,FALSE);

if (IDOK == dlg.DoModal()) //crash here on right click
{
        //CString folder = dlg.GetFolderPath();
        strFileName = dlg.GetPathName();
        SetFileName ( T2CW (strFileName)); 

}
```

Following is the stack trace

ole32!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance+245
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+5e
ole32!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance+88
ole32!CProcessActivator::CCICallback+4e
ole32!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation+33
ole32!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext+7f
ole32!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance+77
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+5e
ole32!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance+eb
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+5e
ole32!ICoCreateInstanceEx+5f5
ole32!CoCreateInstance+17b
shell32!_SHCoCreateInstance+209
shell32!SHExtCoCreateInstance+28
shell32!DCA_SHExtCoCreateInstance+3d
shell32!HDXA_QueryContextMenu+287
shell32!CDefFolderMenu::QueryContextMenu+625
shell32!CContextMenuOnContextMenuArray::_QueryNthContextMenu
shell32!CContextMenuOnContextMenuArray::QueryContextMenu+b0
shell32!CDefView::_DoContextMenuPopup+19d
shell32!CDefView::OnBackgroundContextMenu+2d1
shell32!CListViewHost::ShowContextMenu+1f1
shell32!CDefView::_OnContextMenu+110
shell32!CDefView::WndProc+889
shell32!CDefView::s_WndProc+7c
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!CallWindowProcAorW+dc
user32!CallWindowProcW+18
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallOriginalWndProc+1d
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!DefSubclassProc+7c
shell32!DefSubclassProc+56
shell32!CListViewHost::_ViewSubclassWndProc+3e1
shell32!CListViewHost::s_ViewSubclassWndProc+4f
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!MasterSubclassProc+e7
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!DispatchClientMessage+c3
user32!_fnDWORD+2d
ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
user32!ZwUserMessageCall+a
user32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+a4
user32!RealDefWindowProcW+5a
uxtheme!DoMsgDefault+2a
uxtheme!OnDwpContextMenu+ef
uxtheme!_ThemeDefWindowProc+209
uxtheme!ThemeDefWindowProcW+11
user32!DefWindowProcW+e6
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CListView::WndProc+2a42
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CListView::s_WndProc+6cd
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!CallWindowProcAorW+dc
user32!CallWindowProcW+18
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallOriginalWndProc+1d
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!DefSubclassProc+7c
shell32!DefSubclassProc+56
shell32!CListViewHost::s_ListViewSubclassWndProc+31e
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!MasterSubclassProc+e7
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!SendMessageWorker+682
user32!SendMessageW+5c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CLVMouseManager::HandleMouse+f8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CListView::WndProc+9dc
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CListView::s_WndProc+6cd
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!CallWindowProcAorW+dc
user32!CallWindowProcW+18
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallOriginalWndProc+1d
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!DefSubclassProc+7c
shell32!DefSubclassProc+56
shell32!CListViewHost::s_ListViewSubclassWndProc+31e
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!CallNextSubclassProc+8c
comctl32_7fefbdd0000!MasterSubclassProc+e7
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+1ad
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+3b5
user32!IsDialogMessageW+153
user32!DialogBox2+197
user32!InternalDialogBox+135
user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW+58
user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamW+18
comdlg32!CFileOpenSave::Show+1af
comdlg32!_InvokeNewFileOpenSave+db
comdlg32!CSTADialog::s_DialogThreadProc+2d
shlwapi!WrapperThreadProc+19b
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d

Comment: Do you mean right-click on a file shown in the file list, or just a random right-click somewhere in the dialog's UI?

Comment: When I right click to create a new folder

Comment: This code works fine in my environment. May be you have an Explorer addin that causes the Crash. Look at the call stack in the Debugger. Who is causing the Crash?

Comment: Does it also crash on another computer or only on your developement machine ?

Comment: @Michael It crashes on all machines

Comment: It works fine here. Write a dummy application from scratch and try your code from there and see it it crashes or not. What version of Visual Studio do you use ?

Comment: Does it crash also from other applications not written by you?

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli The same code does not crash in other applications

Comment: If the same code does not crash in other applications, the problem must be somewhere in your application. Try to strip down your application until the crash doesn't occur anymore (that may be quite hard though).

Comment: You said *"it crashes"* but did not provide details. How does it crash? If a debugger is attached, enable breaking into the debugger when an exception is **thrown** to see where it crashes.

Comment: @IInspectable  it crashes in DoModal()..Access Voilation C000005

Comment: a stacktrace might be helpful

Comment: You don't need a stack trace. You have the source code and you have the .pdb. Just look at the offending line and see which (class) member cannot be accessed.

Comment: @Michael Stack trace has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue gets resolved if I disable the NVDIA CPL Context Menu Extension from the context menu . However its still a mystery as the same code does work for other applications .